# How to solve TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in my GTIN code

Tags: python, validation

I am creating a code that checks the 8th digit of a 7 digit GTIN 8 number and then tells you if it is a vaild GTIN number. But I get this message and do not know what to do to fix it.

How should I alter my code to stop this problem and have the functions of the code work? Thanks

CODE:

```
while 2>1:
GTIN = input("Enter 7 digit number for check-digit. Enter 8 digit number for validity.")
if not GTIN.isdigit() or not len(GTIN) == 7:
    print("invalid entry...")
    continue

a = int(GTIN[0])*3
b = int(GTIN[1])*1
c = int(GTIN[2])*3
d = int(GTIN[3])*1
e = int(GTIN[4])*3
f = int(GTIN[5])*1
g = int(GTIN[6])*3

total = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)

checkdigit = (total + 9) // 10 * 10 - total

if len(GTIN) == 7:
    print("Your check digit is",checkdigit)

if sum(total)%10==0:
    print("Valid GTIN-8 number")
else:
    print("Invalid GTIN number")
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> if sum(total)%10==0:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: You can replace `while 2>1:` with `while True:`...

Comment: thanks for the improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception occurs because `sum` expects a sequence (for example a list of numbers) as its argument, but you have passed it a single integer (or int), `total`.  An int is not composed of other objects, so you cannot iterate over it like you can with a list or set, for example, hence the TypeError.

`total` is already the sum of a, b, c, d, e, f, and g, so you don't need to call sum on it.

Just do

```
if total % 10 == 0:
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer